# Signalr negotiate url fails

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

Trying to get signalr up and running.
I keep getting 2 errors back from the server:

1. GET negotitate url returns 500 Internal Server Error
2. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:10772//signalr/negotiate ...
   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Screenshot provided.

Any ideas?

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixRvP.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found it out myself. Spelling error.
The name of the hub mentioned was incorrect.

changed:
`var proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('chattAppHub');`

to:
**`var proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('ChatAppHub');`**

In the backend:


**[HubName("ChatAppHub")]**
public class ChatAppHub : Hub ...

inside startup.cs

`var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
      hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
appBuilder.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
appBuilder.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);`

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

C# Startup.cs tweak:

```
app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration{EnableJSONP = true});
```

JavaScript tweak:

```
connection.start({ jsonp: true })
```

We need JSONP anyways so for us it was a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it is all about CORS.
You should add Host URL in CORS config in Sturtup.cs, Have look at:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59891997/854405